# Strange behavior from println

Tags: java

I have not coded in Java in a while. I am finding the first 100 primes that is also a palindrome, now when I run the following code:

```
public class PalindromPrime {
    /**
     * Main: Prints out the first 100 PalindromPrimes in tabular format
     */
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int num = 0;
        int myNumber = 2;
        int lineCounter = 0;
        while(num < 100){
            if(isPrime(myNumber)){
                
                num++;
                if(lineCounter % 10 == 0){
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
                System.out.println(myNumber);
                //System.out.printf("%5d", myNumber);
                lineCounter++;
            }
            myNumber++;
        }
        
    }

    //Checks if the number is a prime number
    public static boolean isPrime(int myNumber){
        for(int i = 0; i <= myNumber / 2; i++){
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Java gives me output that frankly does not make any sense to me?? Can someone explain this to me?

```
-2147483648
-2147483647
-2147483646
-2147483645
-2147483644
-2147483643
-2147483642
-2147483641
-2147483640
-2147483639

-2147483638
-2147483637
-2147483636
-2147483635
-2147483634
-2147483633
-2147483632
-2147483631
-2147483630
-2147483629

-2147483628
-2147483627
-2147483626
-2147483625
-2147483624
-2147483623
-2147483622
-2147483621
-2147483620
-2147483619

-2147483618
-2147483617
-2147483616
-2147483615
-2147483614
-2147483613
-2147483612
-2147483611
-2147483610
-2147483609

-2147483608
-2147483607
-2147483606
-2147483605
-2147483604
-2147483603
-2147483602
-2147483601
-2147483600
-2147483599

-2147483598
-2147483597
-2147483596
-2147483595
-2147483594
-2147483593
-2147483592
-2147483591
-2147483590
-2147483589

-2147483588
-2147483587
-2147483586
-2147483585
-2147483584
-2147483583
-2147483582
-2147483581
-2147483580
-2147483579

-2147483578
-2147483577
-2147483576
-2147483575
-2147483574
-2147483573
-2147483572
-2147483571
-2147483570
-2147483569

-2147483568
-2147483567
-2147483566
-2147483565
-2147483564
-2147483563
-2147483562
-2147483561
-2147483560
-2147483559

-2147483558
-2147483557
-2147483556
-2147483555
-2147483554
-2147483553
-2147483552
-2147483551
-2147483550
-2147483549
```

Why is it a bunch of negative values??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not `println` that is at fault.  It is the logic in your `isPrime` method.

The number never returns true until the number increments and gets integer overflow, **wrapping around to the most negative number,** and then the test in the for loop always fails so the function always returns true.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be in the IF statement in the isPrime method.

You are currently referencing **i** not the number itself.

```
Change to:
    if(**myNumber** % 2 == 0){
                    return false;
                }
```

Output: 3, 5, 7, 9, ..

Answer (score 1):

The isPrime method needs to be corrected..

```
public static boolean isPrime(int myNumber) {
    for (int i = 2; i < (myNumber / 2) + 1; i++) {
        if (myNumber % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now for explanation of the problem...

In your code, instead of checking if number is divisible by index (`myNumber % i`), you are mistakenly just dividing the index i by 2 (`i % 2 == 0`) and are checking if it is 0. And since i is always starting count from 0, and the for condition is always satisfied for all positive numbers (`i <= myNumber / 2`), the loop always starts and returns false as the condition (`i % 2 == 0`) is always met.

Once myNumber in your main function finally cycles till `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and then reaches -ve numbers, your condition for loop `i <= myNumber / 2` is finally not getting satisfied, and you are getting a true back from the function.

Hence essentially you are printing the 100 numbers counting backwards from `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Hope this clarifies. I am sure you were getting results after a wait too..